# android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources() error when using github repository

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText to enter currency into my application and I am using this code:

```
 CurrencyEditText cet = new CurrencyEditText(this, null);
```

Here is the logcat:

```
                                                                       Process: com.dharquissandas.budget, PID: 17620
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dharquissandas.budget/com.dharquissandas.budget.add_expense}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
                                                                           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
                                                                           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4306)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4454)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:995)
                                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:79)
                                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:75)
                                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:71)
                                                                           at com.blackcat.currencyedittext.CurrencyEditText.<init>(CurrencyEditText.java:33)
                                                                           at com.dharquissandas.budget.add_expense.<init>(add_expense.java:29)
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

What am I doing wrong I don't know, I am fairly new to android programming can someone help me out. What am I supposed to put in the attribute part of the code?

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/57mTUMWX

Comment: You can't instantiate a `View` outside of a class method, as the required `Context` won't be initialized yet. Move the instantiation into `onCreate()`, for example.

Comment: post your related code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating view elements in your Code.
Add the view for CurrencyText to your XML.

Then you make sure it has an @+id/myName and find it by doing

```
CurrencyText myText = findViewById(R.id.myName);
```

Comment: Then share your xml file and the onCreate where you findViewbyId because there should not be an issue if you have it setup correctly

Comment: I never saw you reply, my apologies. Did you get this resolved? your error is pointing to your getResources() call saying the object calling it is null. This is either in your code (if you are a fragment that is not attached yet) or could be in the CurrencyEditText code newing one up in code may cause them to do getResource calls as well on a particular item. You may comment out their code and see if the crash goes away to help narrow it down

Comment: Yeah, I got to this conclusion afterwards, thank you for checking back though